Blazor Server External Links routing to Not Found
My website is https://medbase.co.zw.
If I navigate to a page within the app, it works. But if I copy and paste the url into another tab, it routes to not found.
https://medbase.co.zw/questions/13 Try clicking this
This started after I changed the app to .NET 8, removing the _Host.cshtml, renamimg App to Routes and App becoming what it is now. In addition, I have had to add the <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" /> and <Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" /> so that the app works with MudBlazor. I find that if I remove the render mode tag, MudBlazor navigation panels do not work.
Relevant code pasted below
App.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="MedbaseBlazor.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="_content/MedbaseComponents/wwwroot/css/mdstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/MedbaseComponents/wwwroot/css/common.css" />

    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--WhatsApp Metas-->
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Medbase">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="~/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="~/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="~/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="~/site.webmanifest">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#80b0fa">

    <!--Mudblazor References-->
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <!--Microsoft Clarity-->

    <!--Google Ads Line-->

</head>
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Routes.razor
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly"
        AdditionalAssemblies="new[]
        {
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Questions).Assembly, 
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Topics).Assembly, 
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Store.Store).Assembly,
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Essays.Essays).Assembly,
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Articles.Articles).Assembly,
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Notes.Notes).Assembly,
            typeof(MedbaseComponents.Pages.Questions2.QuestionsPage2).Assembly,
        }">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(WebLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

Program.cs
using MedbaseLibrary.Services;
using MudBlazor;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using MedbaseBlazor;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using MedbaseBlazor.Pages;
using MedbaseLibrary.Essays;
using MedbaseLibrary.Notes;
using Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using MedbaseLibrary.Store;
using MedbaseLibrary.Questions;
using MedbaseLibrary.CoursesAndTopics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddServiceDefaults();

var environment = args.Contains("--local") ? Environments.Development : Environments.Production;

//Dependencies
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;


builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddMudMarkdownServices();
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode/{0}");

app.Run();



The problem is that while the Blazor SPA router knows about the routes through the registration of the additional assemblies in Router, the Server Side router doesn't.
You need to register the libraries in program in MapRazorComponents:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(.... add all your assemblies here);


That's not working, it's saying the assemblies have already been registered. I removed them from Router to Program.cs

I just clicked you are using Per Page/Component Interactivity.  Is that what you intend?  Here's a demo project I did for another similar question the other day that uses global interactivity - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO79028139.

I will be frankly honest with you. Just starting to really wrap my head around these interactivity issues. When I upgraded, I intended to use Global Interactivity

If you don't want to pull your hair out, go either* Server* or WebAssembly and Global Interactivity.  Leave Auto and/or Per Page/Component well alone unless you  absolutely must.   See https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html for my personal thoughts.
